# How to mimic the OneNote Page Group Print Range Functionality in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf-generation, onenote

I am creating a process using VBA code, via a Microsoft 2013 Access database, to loop through Pages of a 2013/2016 OneNote notebooks, to print the Section’s Pages to pdf files.

I am using the Publish Method (oneNote.Publish pageID, publishContentTo, pfPDF) to print each Section Page, which requires only a single Page ID as the method’s first variable, thus only printing one Section Page per pdf file, whether it be a Page or Subpage.

The code works; however, I need to print the Sub Pages into the same pdf file of its Parent Page.

I know that OneNote has the functionality. If you click File, Print, then Print Preview, the user interface will bring up the Print Preview & Settings Dialog box. In that box, under Settings, there is a dropdown to pick a Print Range. When I select the Page Group range, and print the file, it includes the subpages along with the Parent Page.

Is there a VBA function to mimic printing of the Page Group range, or is there a way using the current Publish Method or any other VBA coding functions or methods?

This is the first time I am coding with OneNote and I am not finding many OneNote/VBA examples.